# Form Action and file Upload, Submit Button always goes to form Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have problem with this form submission, on button click this form straight goes to it's action, but first i want to validate the file upload and save the uploaded file.. but as soon as i click the submit button form goes to the action page.. Do you have any ideas why?
Here is the code:

```
<form action="" id="form2" class="appForm">
                      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <table class="jobTitleTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Job Title</th>
                                    <th>Job Posting Reference</th>
                                    <th>Type of Job</th>
                                    <th>Job Department</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <ul class="jobHeadings">
                                <li class="jobPos"><%# Eval("JobPosition") %></li>
                                <li class="jobCat"><%# Eval("JobCategory") %></li>
                                <li class="jobDate"><%# Eval("Posted", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}")%></li>
                                <li class="jobApplyDate"><%# Eval("ApplyBy", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}")%></li>
                                </ul>
                           <%-- <tbody>
                                    <td class="lftBorder"><%# Eval("JobPosition") %></td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("JobCategory") %></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("ApplyBy") %></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>--%>
                        </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:Repeater> 

                     <fieldset>     
                        <legend>Salary</legend>   
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCurSalary" runat="server" value="" placeholder="Current Salary" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxExpSalary" runat="server" placeholder="Expected Salary" value="" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>  
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>     
                        <legend>Notice Period</legend>   
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtboxNoticePeriod" value="Notice Period Required for Joining" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxExpecjoinDate" value="Expected Date of Joining" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>  
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Details</legend>

                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxPerName" value="Name" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="TxtBoxFatherName" value="Father's Name" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <label class="idCardLbl floatLft">CNIC#</label><asp:TextBox runat="server" class="" id="txtBoxidCard" type="text" value="99999-9999999-9" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formFieldsLft">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="" type="text" value="Family Code" maxlength="6"  onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="formFldsFull">


                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="smallFld" ID="txtBoxPhone" value="Phone" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" /> 
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="smallFld" ID="txtBoxMobile" value="Mobile" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />                       
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="smallFld" ID="txtBoxEmail" value="Email" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
                         </div>
<hr class="formDivider" />
                           <h3 class=" fullwidth">Upload Your CV</h3>
                           <div class="formFldsFull">                                 
                                  <input type="file" />
                            </div>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonSubmit" CommandName="Apply" Class="btns btnRed floatLft" 
                                    Text="Submit"
                                    oncommand="ButtonSubmit_Command" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />

</form>
```

Comment: Is the CausesValidation property on the button set to true or false? You can also investigate about the custom validators provided by ASP.Net

Comment: Set to true but i have set it to false but still it just does not execute to the button_Command instead goes to the action page of the form..

Comment: Clarify "action page of the form"?? Is this even an ASP.Net server side form (re: `runat="server"`)?

Comment: yes the runat form is already on the master page.. action page is mail.aspx which read all the input values from Request.Form["name"]. but before Posting form values to mail.aspx i want to save the uplaoded file.

Comment: use onClientClick="validationFunction() return false;"

Comment: Thank,,,after this i can upload the CV but i can not transfer form field via Post method to mail.aspx. i can achieve the same thing if i remove the action attribute. but i want to upload CV and then show all the filds on Mail.aspx